# After Migration from old Mac to new Mac Stderr:VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'homestead' has terminated unexpectedly.. because of signal 9

Tags: laravel, migration, vagrant, homestead, macos-ventura

I have migrated from MacPro 2017 to MacPro 2019 when I run vagrant up I stuck in the following error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "492bedf4-2a89-455e-9900-97ba2acf456a", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'homestead' has terminated unexpectedly during startup because of signal 9
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

Comment: I voted to close because both vagrant and virtualbox questions are off topic and this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated VirtualBox to the latest version (7.0.12) and It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I have just updated my Mac OS to 14.2.1 (23C71).
After the update, I was facing the same issue.

```
    There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "492bedf4-2a89-455e-9900-97ba2acf456a", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'homestead' has terminated unexpectedly during startup because of signal 9
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I have just updated my Virtual Box to 7.0.12, and it work cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

After doing some R&D I have fixed the issue by reinstalling VirtualBox and Vagrant.
My versions were 7.0.4 and 2.3.3 respectively

Cheers......

Comment: deleting and reinstalling didn't work for me. Did you have to edit any Mac Security or Profile settings?

Comment: No, i didn't change any settings

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me "just reinstall VirtualBox"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35021113)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).